# Problem importing csv file : ABC.csv file in mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a csv file Nifty_PE :

```
01-Dec-2008,       11.76,
02-Dec-2008,       11.65,
03-Dec-2008,       11.64,
04-Dec-2008,       12.22,
05-Dec-2008,       11.90,
08-Dec-2008,       12.20,
10-Dec-2008,       12.84,
11-Dec-2008,       12.80,
12-Dec-2008,       12.81,
15-Dec-2008,       13.07,
16-Dec-2008,       13.33,
```

When i give the following cmd in mathematica :

```
Take[Import["C:\\Users\\ROHAN\Desktop\\NIFTY_PE.csv", "CSV"], 5]
```

I get the output as :

```
{{"01-Dec-2008", 11.76, ""}, {"02-Dec-2008", 11.65, 
  ""}, {"03-Dec-2008", 11.64, ""}, {"04-Dec-2008", 12.22, 
  ""}, {"05-Dec-2008", 11.9, ""}}
```

What i desire to get is :

```
{{"01-Dec-2008", 11.76}, {"02-Dec-2008",...........
```

Kindly help me what i should do to get the desired output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\ROHAN\Desktop\\NIFTY_PE.csv", "CSV"][[1;;5, 1;;2]]
```

`[[1;;5, 1;;2]]` indexes only a part of the returned array.  `1;;5` means rows 1 through 5.  `1;;2` means columns 1 and 2 -- ignoring the empty third column.  If you want to keep all rows instead of just the first five, use `[[All, 1;;2]]`.

All of this is documented under the function [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html).

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
Take[Import["C:\\Users\\ROHAN\Desktop\\NIFTY_PE.csv", "CSV"], 5, 2]
```

which would take the first 2 columns of the first 5 rows of the imported table.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively *2, if you don't know (or don't wish to check in advance) the desired dimensions of your matrix you can use a replacement rule.

```
Import["C:\\Users\\ROHAN\Desktop\\NIFTY_PE.csv", "CSV"] /. "" -> Sequence[]
```

Or if you are concerned that there might also be blanks somewhere other than at the end of a row, and you only want to eliminate the ones at the end of the row:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\ROHAN\Desktop\\NIFTY_PE.csv", "CSV"] /. {a__,""} -> {a}
```

Comment: This could have lots of un expected side effects that could be very annoying. The positions of "" could be spread out among many different columns, be in some rows but no others. Which could cause a mess.

Comment: @Davorak, in principle yes, but the specific issue is the CSV does tend to add a blank column at the end of the row. I will add a more specific replacement rule to my answer which will be safer.